# Subversion HTTPS password caching using GPG-Agent?

Tags: svn, https, gnupg, gpg-agent

I am using the Subversion client (version 1.9.5 r1770682, installed from the default package repository) on a Debian Stretch machine, to which I only have SSH access. I am connecting to a Subversion repository via HTTPS and would like to avoid having to re-type my password every time I perform an `svn up` or `svn ci` command. I would also like to avoid having to store the password on disk as plaintext.

The [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.creds) suggests that I should be able to use GPG-Agent as a means of caching my password. Although `svn --version` reports that the GPG-Agent authentication credential cache should be available, I am having some trouble getting it to work.

With regard to GPG, I have created a GPG key pair, have added `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` to my `.profile` file, and have verified that GPG works by encrypting and decrypting a piece of text.

With regard to Subversion, in my `.subversion/config` file, I have set the following:

```
$ grep '^[^#]' < .subversion/config
[auth]
password-stores = gpg-agent
[helpers]
[tunnels]
[miscellany]
[auto-props]
[working-copy]
```

In my `.subversion/servers` file, I have set the following:

```
$ grep '^[^#]' < .subversion/servers
[groups]
[global]
store-passwords = yes
store-plaintext-passwords = no
```

When I perform an `svn` command, however, no passwords are cached. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong? Has anyone used GPG-Agent successfully for caching HTTPS passwords? (Perhaps this credential cache is only intended for SVN+SSH connections?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem by looking into it once more, starting from the suggestion of Roman above. The comments of the `find_gpg_agent_socket` function in the Subversion client's [GPG-Agent authentication source code](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_subr/gpg_agent.c) indeed explain:

> `$GPG_AGENT_INFO` takes precedence, if set, otherwise `$GNUPGHOME` will be used.
>
> (...)
>
> For reference `GPG_AGENT_INFO` consists of 3 : separated fields. The path to the socket, the pid of the gpg-agent process and finally the version of the protocol the agent talks.

The path to the GPG-Agent socket can easily be found by calling `gpgconf --list-dirs agent-socket` on the command line. The other two segments of the `$GPG_AGENT_INFO` variable are not used by the Subversion client, and should thus not necessarily be set.

I have therefore added the following code at the end of my `.profile` file:

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_AGENT_INFO=`gpgconf --list-dirs agent-socket | tr -d '\n' && echo -n ::`
```

This sets the `$GPG_TTY` variable to the current terminal, and the `$GPG_AGENT_INFO` variable to the GPG-Agent socket, followed by two colon characters (i.e., the format expected by the Subversion source code).

**Subversion seems to cache the repositories' authentication settings** in `~/.subversion/auth`, so I found it necessary to clear that directory before GPG-Agent would be used correctly:

```
rm -rf ~/.subversion/auth
```

After starting a new session, you should be able to verify that the `$GPG_AGENT_INFO` variable is set correctly: `echo $GPG_AGENT_INFO` should output something like `/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent::` (where `1000` is the uid of the current user).

When performing a Subversion command, for example `svn up`, your password will be prompted the first time:

```
Updating '.':
Enter your Subversion password for <https://example.com:443> Subversion Repository
Password for 'username': :
At revision 123.
```

When performing a second Subversion command for the same repository for some time afterwards, Subversion should use the password cached by GPG-Agent:

```
Updating '.':
At revision 123.
```

**Edit:** I have the impression that, when using a repository for the *first* time (i.e., when it is not yet present in Subversion's cache), the password is only correctly saved by GPG-Agent after entering it *twice*.

Comment: It works for me except every day or so I have to enter the password again.  This question https://superuser.com/questions/1584409/can-i-tell-the-gpg-agent-to-never-ask-me-for-a-password asks about that but there's not a good answer.

Comment: After upgrading the OS on a server running, storage of encrypted SVN credentials in GPG-Agent was nuked and was killing one of my crontab jobs. This saved me! As @AdamS noted, I was prompted once more for the password in an odd sort of dialog, but it works without fault afterwards. Update: this actually *does not* solve the crontab issue as GPG-Agent stores passwords in memory, and not on disk. So, as soon as you logout of your session, the stored password will no longer be available.

Comment: From gpg-agent manual, `gpg-agent --daemon --enable-ssh-support --write-env-file "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info"`, then in ~/.profile, `. "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info"` and export the relevant environment vars. `gpgconf` is not needed. https://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg-agent

Comment: This did not work for me, but [this](https://www.dhiller.de/2018/10/04/svn-gpg-agent.html) did.

Answer (score 2):

This thread seems to give a hint: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/subversion_users/WS8Cr7mAovQ

I'm running Xfce on Ubuntu, and I had the same problem. Apparently, the reason is that the `$GPG_AGENT_INFO` environment variable is not set. Manually running the /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90gpg-agent script (which sets this variable) did help me.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Your suggestion is not an immediate solution to my problem, as I do not run an X11 system on my machine, but it (finally) helped me to find a solution! (I will add it below.)